# Is there a native way to HTML escape character entities in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html-entities, html-escape-characters

The Unicode character  given by point `134069`, has the HTML escape `&#x20BB5;`

Is there a (preferably native) way to get the HTML escapes for character entities from Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get both the point and hex values of the char like this:

```
var codePoint = ''.codePointAt(0); //codePoint = 134069
var hexValue = ''.codePointAt(0).toString(16); //hexValue = 20bb5
var htmlEscape = '&#x' + hexValue + ';'; //htmlEscape = &#x20bb5;
```

Here is a working example:

```js
$('#doIt').click(function() {
  $('#outputHex').html($('#inputText').val().codePointAt(0).toString(16));
  $('#outputString').html('&amp;#x' + $('#inputText').val().codePointAt(0).toString(16) + ';');
  $('#outputChar').html('&#x' + $('#inputText').val().codePointAt(0).toString(16) + ';');
});
```

```css
code {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="inputText"></textarea>
<button id="doIt">do it</button>

<h3>result</h3>
<code id="outputHex"></code>
<code id="outputString"></code>
<code id="outputChar"></code>
```

One more thing, codePointAt is an ES6 function and isn't supported in older browsers. In case the browser blocks the code from running here: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k54jxo1v/)

Comment: This is a good idea however I do not think that it works for all HTML entities (i.e. the `&` is more complicated correct)?

Comment: No. this should work for any character. There are special characters, like & that have shortcuts, i.e. &amp; but this will also work. I will update my answer with a JFiddle example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that converts all non-ASCII7 characters, and `<`, `>`, `&` to HTML entities:

```js
function htmlEntities(s) {
    return Array.from(s).map(function (c) {
        return c.codePointAt(0) < 128 && '<&>'.indexOf(c) == -1 
            ? c 
            : '&#x' + c.codePointAt(0).toString(16) + ';';
    }).join('');
}

var s = 'This is \u{20BB5}, a special character & encoded in HTML.';
document.body.innerHTML = htmlEntities(s);
```

Be aware that in Javascript strings, extended unicode characters are counted as two characters (for example in `length`). The ES6 constructs like `Array.from`, `[...s]` make sure you get the right chunks.

Comment: Wow, this will needlessly bloat HTML for many languages. 99.9% of non-ASCII characters do not need to be encoded as entities. For example, this would make Chinese text take at least 5× more HTML bytes. To anyone reading this, be sure that this is really the solution you need. It probably isn't.

Comment: @AlanH., it seemed what the OP was asking -- they gave as example ``, which indeed does not *need* to be encoded as entity, but yet the OP *asked* for it. It would be more useful if you would put such a comment to the OP...